# ¿Cuál es la palabra más ampliamente reconocida para "crear un índice"? ¿"Indexar", "indizar" o alguna otra?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, español-neutral, informática, argentina

Estaba leyendo en Stack Overflow en español una [espléndida pregunta - respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/308568/83) que habla de los índices de colecciones, listas, etc. Su título inicial decía:

> ¿Por qué ciertos lenguajes de programación **indizan** las colecciones de datos a partir de 1?

Otro usuario de España como yo comentó que la palabra *indizar* sonaba rarísima. Lo mismo a mí, así que propuse cambiarlo a:

> ¿Por qué en ciertos lenguajes de programación el primer **índice** de las colecciones de datos es el 1?

Lo interesante vino luego, pues el autor, argentino, dijo:

> tampoco me suena del todo bien, lo que ocurre es que en Argentina hablar de indexación tiene una connotación algo negativa, es el proceso de ajuste por inflación de los precios.

Le comenté mi cambió y me hizo ver que efectivamente [indizar](https://dle.rae.es/indizar) existe:

> [**indizar**](https://dle.rae.es/indizar)
>   `Haplología de *indicizar, y este de índice e -izar.`
>
> 1. tr. [**indexar**](https://dle.rae.es/indexar#9Ek7nx5).
>
> > 1. tr. Hacer índices de algo.
> >
> > 2. tr. Registrar ordenadamente datos e informaciones, para elaborar su índice.

Es decir, que *indizar* es una [haplología](https://dle.rae.es/?w=haplolog%C3%ADa) (concepto que desconocía y definido como *Eliminación de una sílaba semejante a otra contigua de la misma palabra; p. ej., cejunto por cejijunto, impudicia por impudicicia.*) de *indicizar*, ya no existente. En cualquier caso, sugiere *indexar* como palabra preferida.

Sin embargo, el hecho que en Argentina *indexar* tenga la connotación económica me hace plantear: ¿es *indexar* un concepto que podamos aceptar comúnmente o hay algún otro que plantee el mismo significado sin ambigüedad posible?

Comment: Creo recordar que "indizar" lo he visto (y adoptado) alguna vez en un texto editorial (traducción del inglés) del siglo pasado, en relación al proceso de agregar datos o atributos a las imágenes digitalizadas. En inglés sin duda es "index".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedo preguntarle a mis compañeritos desarrolladores, pero por lo pronto *indizar* suena totalmente extraño a mis oídos (aunque está claro lo que significa), y jamás la he oído usar en Argentina. (Yo habría creído que se trata de una derivación normal sobre *índice*, no una haplología.)

*Indexar* tiene una acepción técnica, económica, que quizá por ser específica no aparece en el DLE: significa "ajustar los precios de los bienes y servicios según un [índice](https://dle.rae.es/%C3%ADndice)" (donde un índice es una "expresión numérica de la relación entre dos cantidades"), generalmente el índice de inflación. El hecho de que en Argentina haya crónicamente una inflación galopante ha hecho que lamentablemente este término nos sea familiar a muchos no economistas.

De todas formas *indexar* sigue sin ser una palabra común, y sus connotaciones negativas sólo aparecen en un contexto bien definido. Si digo

> ¿Por qué ciertos lenguajes de programación indexan las colecciones de datos a partir de 1?

no es posible interpretarlo de otra forma que como debería ser, y la connotación negativa de "indexar precios por inflación" no se me cruzaría por la cabeza. Todo depende del cristal con que se mire; es posible que otra persona esté pensando en ese preciso momento en la indexación que va a sufrir su contrato de alquiler el año próximo, y la idea le vuelva a la mente cada vez que escucha el término *indexar*... Pero en general, para este propósito, la gente no usa *indexar* sino el más genérico *ajustar*.

De manera que *indexar* debería funcionar perfectamente en un texto sobre programación (o sobre libros y bibliotecas, por caso).

Answer (score 3):

Ya que soy el culpable de esta pregunta, y aunque no agregaré mucho más a lo que ya dijo @pablodf76, quiero comentar que haciendo un poco de memoria, el término "indizar" tiene un uso extendido en las áreas de gestión documental, por ejemplo la norma ISO 5963 habla de ["indización"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indizaci%C3%B3n):

> **Norma internacional ISO 5963**: documentación, métodos para el análisis de documentos, la
>   determinación de su contenido y la selección de los términos de
>   **indización**

Evidentemente el termino "indizar" es un "uso y costumbre" personal, producto de haber trabajado hace mucho tiempo atrás con procesos de gestión documental electrónicos. 
En lo que a mi respecta, a partir de hoy, para el contexto que menciona fedorqui, el término a usar debiera ser "indexan".

Comment: ¡Interesante! Gracias por pasarte por aquí para indicarnos cuál es tu uso, más allá del que indicaba en la pregunta. Curioso que la página de la Wikipedia tenga peticiones de unión con _indexación_.